# FastAPI returning a bad file between two API endpoints

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi, bytesio

I am working with two FastAPI APIs, but for some reason, the BytesIO object (a wave file) get corrupted / isn't properly complete when it reaches the other endpoint from the other API.

The codes follows:

API1:

```
`
(...)

    audio = tts.generate_audio(translation,final,wavdata)
    samples, samplerate = sf.read(audio)
    sd.play(samples, samplerate)
    sd.wait()
    with open("obj1.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(audio, f)
    return Response(content=audio.read(), media_type="audio/wav")
```

`

API2:

`
(...)

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
audio = io.BytesIO(r.content)
with open("obj.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(audio, f)
(...)
```

`

API1 is sending an audio object to API2, however, after checking the pickle dump files (both are for BytesIO objects), I noticed the pickle file from API1 has 33kb while the pickle file from API2 has just 42bytes. What is happening here, and how to fix this problem?

I tried sending a file from one endpoint in one API to another endpoint in another API, but it is not working. I expected to receive an exact same copy of the file on the other endpoint.

Comment: Does your second call to `audio.read()` actually do what you expect it to do? i.e. does pickling the object _read the file_, which means that it won't be read a second time? You might want to read the data first, and then both pickle and return that content.

Comment: "audio" is a BytesIO object. The first "read()"' is from the Soundfile library, not from the BytesIO. The second read() is to convert the BytesIO object into bytes. On the second API, I convert the bytes object back to BytesIO. But when checking the pickle dump, I see it's no longer the same object (different file sizes)

Comment: So what does the pickle file actually contain? Have you verified what you're returning? (i.e. is the issue on the server or the client); have you verified what you're giving to FastAPI? Is it the actual data, or just an empty string? etc. You need to actually do a bit of debugging to find out where your assumptions are wrong :-)